# When I paste in the terminal sometimes the contents are prefixed with the characters '^[[200~'

Tags: gnome-terminal

Sometimes when I paste text from the clipboard into the terminal, the resulting text has the following characters added to the front '^[[200~'.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you try googling `"^[[200~" terminal`?

Comment: Are you pasting with the keyboard or the mouse?  If keyboard, does this only happen when you try to paste again after first forgetting the shift?

Comment: I see the same on MATE terminal too. What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: @FedKad i did try. that is the first link  XD

Comment: For help, also look [at this very related post on superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1532688/75914).

Answer (score 24):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in a terminal doesn't paste as you might expect.  By default, programs which use the *Readline* library, such as `bash`, will treat the next character literally when they receive this, and not as a control code.

You need to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste text.  This is handled by the terminal itself, and only that pasted text is seen by *Readline*.

Or, at least that used to be true.

If a program has told the terminal they understand them, as *Readline* has started doing by default since Ubuntu 20.04, this text will be wrapped by the terminal with *paste brackets*, control codes `^[[200~` and `^[[201~`.

Guess what happens if you type  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> immediately followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> when you realized your mistake.

Yes, the opening paste bracket `^[[200~` will be pasted as text, and not interpreted as a control code.

---

One fix for this is to tell *Readline* to ignore <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  To do this, add the following to your `~/.inputrc` file (creating it if necessary):

```
"\C-v": ""
```

This overrides the default binding of:

```
"\C-v": quoted-insert
```

The <kbd>Insert</kbd> key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> remain bound to `quoted-insert` should you ever need this for some reason.

---

Alternatively, if you're now thinking *"What's the point of bracketed-paste?"*, you could instead disable it in *Readline* by adding to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste off
```

But, ironically, *bracketed-paste* tells programs to treat that pasted text literally, and not to interpret it like keyboard input.  You may or may not like this.

This allows you, for example in `bash`, to edit multiple pasted lines before they are executed, as only newlines from the keyboard cause execution of code.

Comment: This also happens on Shift+Insert or Ctrl+Shift+V, so answer is not accurate.

Comment: I am surprised this was downvoted, it's a gem of great info, thanks Martin